# Javascript Singleton design pattern and closure

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a Singleton object that deals with servicing an event listener:

```
var ChildParent = (function () {
   var html_element = document.getElementById("quoteNum");
   var row_number = 0;

   return {
       init: function(){
           html_element["parenttype"+row_number].addEventListener("click", ChildParent.fire, false);
       },
       add: function(total) { //Adding a row

       },
       fire: function() {
           alert("it fired!");
       }
   } 
})();
```

However, when I call ChildParent.init(), the document-element will not get assigned to html_element, so i can't attach the listener. Oddly enough, the row_number variable is initialized to zero.  Is there some sort of scoping conflict that I don't understand?  When i use the step-into feature of opera's dragonfly, I can't create var assignments when in the init() function.

Comment: quoteNum is a <div> element.  parenttype0 is an <input> element inside the <div> that im using to list parent/child relationships for a record (quotes and invoices).

Comment: So that is the `id` of the input?  Is `html_element` null or is it `html_element[...]` which is coming back undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure element with id "quoteNum" is available on the page when you are executing your script.
It may happen that you are executing the script without waiting for all the page elements to be rendered.

You may think about handling [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload).

**Update**

the following change could help you fix the issue with html_element being initialized before the page is rendered.

```
var ChildParent = (function () {
   function getElement(){
       return html_element ? html_element : html_element = document.getElementById("quoteNum");
   }

   var html_element;
   var row_number = 0;

   return {
       init: function(){
           getElement()["parenttype"+row_number].addEventListener("click", ChildParent.fire, false);
       },
       add: function(total) { //Adding a row

       },
       fire: function() {
           alert("it fired!");
       }
   } 
})();
```

Comment: I'm using <body onload="docReady();">.  The docReady() function runs ParentChild.init(), so the page is fully loaded.

Comment: @zshfalcon html_element gets assigned when ChildParent is created, not when you call init.

Comment: Thanks I just figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Is the above code executed **after** the element with id `quoteNum` exists in the DOM?

If not `html_element` will be `null`.

So make sure that all the above code is in a script tag that occurs somewhere in the document below the element (or is in a `window.onload` jQuery's document ready type event).

Comment: Its called from a body.onload function.  I have used the step-into features of dragonfly to make sure that the document element exists. The steps i took are the following:  
I stepped into the body-onload.
I traced traced the function calls to the ChildParent.init().
I used the javascript console to verify the element was loaded.
I can see the element on the page.

Comment: @zshfalcon `init()` is too late. Your `html_element` variable gets assigned when `ChildParent`'s initialiser runs.